# Массив собственного типа и конструктор с аргументом

Tags: c++, объекты, конструктор

Добрый день!
Подскажите есть ли способ передать аргумент при инициализации динамического массива.

```
struct MyStruct
{
  int a;
  MyStruct(int _a)
    {
      a = _a;
    }
};
int main()
{
  int n = 3; 
  MyStruct *obj = new MyStruct[n];
  return 0;
}
```

Хочу получить примерно такое, для каждого объекта свое значение.
Но как это сделать не могу понять.

```
MyStruct *obj = new MyStruct[n] { 1 1 1 .. 1 };
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если хотите инициализировать элементы каждый раз  какими то конкретными значениями:

```
template <int k = 1>
struct Mystruct {
    int a;
    Mystruct(int n = k) : a(n) {} 
};
int main()
{   
    const int n = 10;
    Mystruct<>* obj1 = new Mystruct<>[n];    // все элементы 1
    Mystruct<2>* obj2 = new Mystruct<2>[n];  // все элементы  2
    Mystruct<3>* obj3 = new Mystruct<3>[n];  //  все элементы 3
...  
    return 0;
}
```

так хотели?

но я бы воспользовался STL контейнерами

```
 vector<int>* p1 = new vector<int>(n, 1),
            *p2 = new vector<int>(n, 2),
            *p3 = new vector<int>(n, 3);
```

хотя для численных методов все же std::valarray для меня предпочтительней

```
сonst int n = 10;
valarray<int>* p = new valarray<int>(1, n);  //   все элементы 1
*p = 2;   // все элементы 2
*p = 3;   // все элементы 3
(*p)[slice(1, n/2, 2)] = 23; // 3, 23, 3, 23, 3, 23, 3, 23, 3, 23
*p = 1;                      // все элементы 1
p = new valarray<int>( p->shift(n/2)); // первая половина 0, вторая 1
```

Comment: Да, то что нужно, спасибо!

Comment: пожалуйста, но я добавил в ответ кое что ;  может вам это будет полезней...

Answer (score 0):

Для начала следует подправить определение структуры:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int a;

    MyStruct(void): a{5} {}

    MyStruct(int _a): a{_a} {}
};
```

Тогда инициализировать можно без проблем:

```
MyStruct * obj{new MyStruct[n]{1, 1, 1}};
```

В случае, когда конструктор с одним аргументом объявлен как `explicit` элементы следует инициализировать явно:

```
MyStruct * obj{new MyStruct[n]{MyStruct{1}, MyStruct{1}, MyStruct{1}}};
```

В случае, когда конструктор по-умолчанию объявлен как `explicit` для инициализации такого массива будет необходимо задавать его размер во время компиляции чтобы не было неявных вызовов этого конструктора:

```
constexpr int n{3};
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я наверно не точно описал свою проблему.
`MyStruct * obj{new MyStruct[n]{1, 1, 1}};`
Такая инициализация не подходит так как я не знаю значение n.
`MyStruct * obj{new MyStruct[n]{1}};` - хочется примерно так, но это не работает.

Comment: Ну тогда после выделения памяти заполнять массив вызвав `std::fill_n`

Comment: Спасибо, придется делать так, хотелось сделать, так что бы нельзя было использовать значения по умолчанию. То есть компилятор ругался при выделении памяти для этого типа.